# Ruby on Rails with Xampp

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, apache, xampp

I have a xampp installed on my windows 7 machine. Now i want to work with Ruby on Rails. For that i have installed Ruby and then installed rails using the command prompt.

Now the problem is that i do not know how to integrate my existing xampp installation with ruby on rails so i can use the Apache server and MySQL databases.

I do not want to install MySQL and some other webserver as it will cause a lot of problems for me. So please guide me about any fixes i should use which will make the apache and MySQL from xampp to work with Ruby on Rails.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [this method](http://www.ralree.com/2006/06/14/mongrel-webrick-forwarding-in-apache/) or try out something like [Passenger](http://www.modrails.com/install.html).

You can just develop using Webrick or Mongrel and worry about Apache in production. Your MySQL installation should work fine with rails as-is. You will  just need to configure your `database.yml` file appropriately based on your MySQL database settings.

Comment: How should i use webrick ? When i use the command "rails server" it does not do anything .. It just gives me options to use with this command. How should i launch webrick ?

Comment: `rails server` should start webrick by default. I recommend going through this guide -> http://railsforzombies.org/, which will help you settle in